# Collections\Criteria::expr(), isNotNull and notLike

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am using `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()` (***NOT** the query builder expression*).

It seems that `isNotNull()` and `notLike()` operators are not implemented in this class.

What is the best way to do `isNotNull()` and `notLike()` in this case?

Answer (score 21):

### Criteria IS NOT NULL

In `doctrine/orm ^2.4` or `doctrine/collections ^1.2` to have an `is not null` that acts like a `Criteria::expr()->isNotNull('field')` you can use

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$expr = $criteria::expr();
$collection->matching($criteria->where($expr->neq('field', null)));
```

This matches the same way the expression builder creates `Expr::isNull` but changes the comparison operator to `Comparison::NEQ` via:

```
return new Comparison($field, Comparison::EQ, new Value(null));
```

Which is then checked for by the [`QueryExpressionVisitor`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryExpressionVisitor.php#L160) and `BasicEntityPersister`, used to build the query as `Expr:isNotNull`.

```php
case Comparison::NEQ:
    if ($this->walkValue($comparison->getValue()) === null) {
        return $this->expr->isNotNull($this->rootAlias . '.' . $comparison->getField());
    }
```

---

### Criteria LIKE and NOT LIKE

For the `Criteria::expr()->like()` functionality, `Criteria::expr()->contains('property', 'value')` is the equivalent of the SQL `property LIKE %value%`. However it does not allow for changing to `value%` or `%value`but a [pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/commit/a079bed36b8f3c421416f61d8cf32d782de00e5c) *(as of 2.5.4)* with the proposed `startsWith` and `endsWith` methods that has been merged with master - so may be released with 2.5.5.

Unfortunately for `Criteria::expr()->notLike()` and the other `LIKE` variants, the `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ExpressionBuilder` used by Criteria does not support them.

Additionally if the comparison operator is not defined *(such as `Comparison::CONTAINS`)*, an error is thrown by the `QueryExpressionVisitor` and `BasicEntityPersister`, which prevents manually defining your own `Comparison` functionality.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

---

### Custom Repository Alternative

The best alternative is to use a custom repository and the DBAL query builder expressions instead to substitute the desired functionality.

Using a custom entity repository to filter the result set will prevent a full-table read of your collections and improve speed when using caching.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

---

### Collection Filter Alternative

An alternative is using `filter` to retrieve a specific subset of objects within a collection.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

```
class MyEntity
{
    public function getCollectionFieldNotLike($value)
    {
        return $this->getCollection()->filter(function($a) use ($value) {
            return (false === stripos($a->getField(), $value));
        });
    }

    public function getCollectionFieldLike($value)
    {
        return $this->getCollection()->filter(function($a) use ($value) {
            return (false !== stripos($a->getField(), $value));
        });
    }
}
```

```
$entity->getCollectionFieldNotLike('value');
$entity->getCollectionFieldLike('value');
```

For procedural syntax combination of both on a repository.

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$expr = $criteria::expr();
$criteria->where($expr->neq('field', null));
$collection = $entityManager->getRepository('app:MyEntity')->matching($criteria);
$collectionNotLike =  $collection->filter(function($a) {
    return (false === strpos($a->getField(), 'value'));
});
```

Keep in mind, as stated above, this will force a full-table read on the collection, since it will need to retrieve the records in order to be able to filter the results.

Comment: Is there any options to get plain SQL from $criteria?
Somethink like $criteria->toString()

Comment: Best bet would be to use the `EntityPersister`. Like so `echo $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister('app:MyEntity')->getSelectSQL($criteria);`

Comment: To get the parameter values use the `expandCriteriaParameters` method on the criteria object. Like so: `list($params, $types) = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityPersister('app:MyEntity')->expandCriteriaParameters($criteria);` Then output the parameters how you like `print_r($params);`

Comment: `$expr->neq('field', null)` does not work in Doctrine 2.3.3, because it results in `field != NULL` instead of `field IS NOT NULL` in the SQL query. You may use a value that is never used regularly instead as a workaround, e.g. `$expr->neq('field', -1)`

Comment: The Comparison operator for [`IS` was changed to `=`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/v1.2/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/Expr/Comparison.php#L36) in Doctrine ORM 2.5 or Doctrine Collections 1.2 However the [`QueryExpressionVisitor` applies `$expr->isNotNull()`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryExpressionVisitor.php#L160) in Doctrine ORM 2.4 applies `Expr:isNotNull()`, updated answer to reflect version constraints and added references